# Long date format doesn't work correctly for en-GB and en-CA culture

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, date-formatting, cultureinfo, reportingservices-2005

For printing a specific report, we are using long date format. The format is culture dependent and it is defined in the placeholder property.

[image]

For en-US the date is printed as per defined format. But when the culture is changed into en-GB or en-CA, the date is not printed as per defined format. The **day name** portion is not printed.

For en-US it's printing `Monday, July 26, 2021`

For en-GB and en-CA it's printing `July 26, 2021`

Even after thorough analysis, we are still unable to find out the cause and solution of such discrepancy. One solution is using the customized date format but that would be highly inefficient given some specific requirements which are not mentioned here.

Is it possible that, for those cultures e.g. en-GB/en-CA long date format does not contain day name hence it's not implemented in SSRS or .NET?

Or is there any issue with my implementation? Even though it's pretty straight forward, am I missing any scenario?

Comment: Even in SSRS 2019 using D as format string doesn't return day as part of the string with the cultures you mention. One workaround is to customize the format string to something like "dddd, d MMMM yyyy" that includes the day.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @niktrs . I've also thought of customized format but that would be highly inefficient given some specific requirements which are not mentioned here. As per current situation it seems like there's no way but to use customized date format.